# Fetching URL parameter and getting regex value in sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, console.log, session-storage, google-developers-console

Trying to figure this out and was hoping someone here can help. Trying to make a JavaScipt that can capture the 'promoCode' parameter without the parameter name and all the junk behind it (other values after the parameter value), and then stores the results in sessionStorage.

Here's an example URL:

```
https://www.constellation.com/solutions/for-your-home/residential-signup.html?zip=77493&promoCode=rockstarcontent/constellation/en/campaigns/DisplayNew2020.html%3futm_source=criteo
```

This is what I want the result to be:
'rockstar'

Notice how I don't want this section 'content/constellation/en/campaigns/DisplayNew2020.html%3futm_source=criteo' and I also don't need anything before the 'promoCode' value.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: 'rockstarcontent' seems to be a single word and there is no way you can extract 'rockstart' unless the the word 'content' is constantly going to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without regex. If you know that it is always on the same position (first in this case) you can use this approach:

```js
const url = 'https://www.constellation.com/solutions/for-your-home/residential-signup.html?zip=77493&promoCode=rockstarcontent/constellation/en/campaigns/DisplayNew2020.html%3futm_source=criteo' 

const n = new URLSearchParams(url);
const o = Object.fromEntries(n.entries());
const w = o.promoCode.split("/")[0]

const s = w.replace("content","");

console.log(s)
```

Comment: Hello @Maik Lowrey. Thank you so much for this. How would you write the JS to fetch the URL directly from the browser (example: window.location.href), and then storing the values in sessionStorage (example: sessionStorage.setItem("promo_code", ???)). I am also curious if we could layer the possibility of other variations in the URL like: https://www.constellation.com/solutions/for-your-home/residential-signup.html?zip=77493&promoCode=rockstarstates/georgia-202110%3futm_source=criteo

Comment: Hello @MaikLowery. I think I got this part figured out. Do you think I'm missing anything else?

var url = window.location.search;
var n = new URLSearchParams(url);
var o = Object.fromEntries(n.entries());
var w = o.promoCode.split("/")[0]
var s = w.replace("content","");
console.log(s)

Comment: @HomeroMiranda Good! That's exactly how I thought it would be. And good because you alone found the function (window.location.search)! :-) And saving in the storage also looks good! `sessionStorage.setItem("key", "value")
console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("key"))`. Good job!

Comment: I am still learning. Thank you for your patience :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = window.location.search;
var n = new URLSearchParams(url);
var o = Object.fromEntries(n.entries());
var w = o.promoCode.split("/")[0]
var s = w.replace("content","");
var s = w.replace("state","");
sessionStorage.setItem("promo_code", (s));
console.log(s)
```